# How to install a SSL Client (not SERVER) Certificate on a shared hosting site?

Tags: apache, ssl, server, shared-hosting, client-certificates

I developed an API that, access is controlled (among other ways) by an SSL Client Certificate. This means that calls made to this API must come from sources that have the SSL Client Certificate installed.

On a Windows machine the process is fairly simple: double click the certificate file, usually a ".p12", and it will run a "Certificate Import Wizard". This seems to be enough if you are using Safari or IE. If you use Chrome or Firefox, you must follow similar "wizards" within them.

But what if I want to install this client certificate in another APACHE shared hosting server? Is it possible? How to install this certificate file on that server and make it applicable to only my shared hosting plan?

Comment: What does this mean? "make it applicable to only my shared hosting plan?"

Comment: The answer will dpened on the software on your server that's querying your API, which will be a PHP script perhaps, or a CGI program.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found out that you, in fact, do not "install" the SSL Client Certificate.

The way I made it work was by creating ".pem" files of the certificate and key ("client.key.pem" and "client.crt.pem") and place them in a folder outside the root folder of my site. The calls (I'm using the cURL library of PHP) refer to these files when the call is made by using the options CURLOPT_SSLCERT and CURLOPT_SSLKEY.

I'm still having other issues with my overall solution, but thought it would be better to post the answer here as, in fact, the question in itself was wrong. If asked on "How to install a SSL Client Certificate on a shared hosting site?", the answer is: "You don't, you simply copy the certificate files to you share and use it in your calls."